# drupal input filter changes only one pattern

Tags: drupal, preg-replace, cdn, fileserver

my custom **drupal** module provides a custom input filter, the function is below:

function my_custom_filter($text) {

```
return preg_replace('~<img(.*)src=\"/sites/default/files/(.*)\"~', '<img$1src="' . variable_get('static_url', "http://fileserver.com") ."/". file_directory_path() . "/" . '$2' . "\"", $text);
```

}

as you can see, i use the module for an cdn fileserver change for the images entered in rte (i use tinymce).

**The problem is**, my filter only changes the last pattern of the given text. I don't understand why this happens, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your .* is being too greedy, and selecting most of the text - from the first '<img' to the last 'src='

Try adding the pcre pattern modifier U (that's capital U) after the second pattern ~.  That will invert the .* parts of the pattern to become ungreedy, and to match as few characters as possible.